# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined when using $(document).ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm using the Foundation CSS framework, which loads jQuery in the footer. This is not atypical and recommended practice by many. However, I need to write scripts in the page. Using document ready should do the trick, but I'm still getting an error. Why?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // My Code
    var a;
    $(#id).dosomething({
    // Doing Something
    });
});
```

Just before body close tag:

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
// More Scripts
</body>
```

But I get the standard error "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" (4x because I have 4 scripts in the body). Also, I cannot move the jQuery reference above the script call as it conflicts with other scripts. I cannot move the script call below jQuery reference either.

Comment: You have to add the dom ready function after jquery is included

Comment: You're missing some quotes there --> `$(#id)` --> `$("#id")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Using document ready should do the trick, but I'm still getting an error. Why?

I think you misunderstood. You use `$(document).ready` to register code that should be executed once the DOM is read, which is typically when you want to manipulate the DOM. `$` is jQuery here, so obviously it has to be loaded before you call `$(document)...`.

> I cannot move the jQuery reference above the script call as it conflicts with other scripts

Maybe you should use [`jQuery.noConflict()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) then.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Looks like the option here is to include the jQuery twice and use noConflict.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit old, but maybe it will help other people.
I got the same error and it was because I loaded my own JS script before the Jquery CDN in the html page.
You must call the JQuery CDN before calling your own script.
`<script src = "https: // jquery-link / .../jquery.js" />`
and after
`<script src = "/ myfoder / myscript.js />`